# Makefile Error?

Tags: batch-file, makefile

I have a makefile which further calls a xml converter tool. The details of the tool and makefile seems irrelevant here. Reason being, there is no problem in the overall makefile, but this xml converter tools fails and returns an error message. Since this is not a makefile error, therefore makefile doesnt stop executing rest of the code. Is there anyway we could avoid this problem? I was thinking of adding a batch file which executes that tool, and then we can call the batch file from the makefile, but then again, how will we know the batch file returned an error? Any hint would be appreciated.

PS: By avoiding the problem, I meant, that makefile should stop when the tool returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

If a `grep` exist on your system, you could do something like the following rule:

```
FILE: DEP-FILE
     ! XMLCONVERTER $< | grep -q "YOUR ERROR STATEMENT"
```

In case that XMLCONVERTER prints "YOUR ERROR STATEMENT" to stdout, a make error is raised.